# C# List removeall taking two arguments in the predicate?

Tags: c#, list, removeall

(I've done as much as possible search based on keywords of "removeall where" or "removeall two argument predicate" without much luck so here goes)

The problem is I have a list of objects (of Class Wave) and a relationship function as:
**private bool AinB(Wave A, Wave B)**, returning true if A 'is in' B. Also AinB(x,y) is true guarantees AinB(y,x) is false.

What's the best way to remove all of the objects in the list where the objects 'is in' another object in the list? i.e., after the removal, the list should only contain objects where neither are in the 'is in' relationship with any other object in the list?

ideally this can be done easily as a

listX.RemoveAll( (x,y) => AinB(x,y)) but of course this is not legal in C#, also there's no easy way to specify which to remove, x or y.

I thought about looping through the list with an index

```
int i = listX.Count - 1;
while (i>=0)
{
    int r = listX.RemoveAll(X => AinB(X, listX[i]));
    i = i - r - 1;
}
```

This seems to work, but I am wondering if there's better way with straight linq code to solve the problem. 
Thanks.

Comment: From the sounds of it you're constructing a tree, is this correct? I'm making the assumption in my answer that AinB is examining the nodes of the tree and determining if `A` is a child of `B`.

Comment: No, it's fairly complex and this 'filter' is just one of the 'relationships' but a dominant one to filter out most of the objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't think of any way to do this that's not at least O(n^2). But the good news is that it's not that hard from a LINQ perspective:

```
listX.RemoveAll(item => listX.Any(isin => AinB(item, isin)));
```

Comment: This seems to be the one I am looking for. Assume listX has the property of being sorted where elements at the end has higher chance of 'enclosing' elements in the fronts, how do I force the evaluation to be from the end back to the front of the list, as in my original loop.

Comment: With these functions, you can't. You may try Reverse, but that's not guaranteed that 'removeall' will visit anything in any order.

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal for loop that inspects the highest element first down to the lowest element in the list. Inspect the element at the current position for any duplicates within the list, if found remove the current element (and possibly decrement your iterator).

Example:

```
List<string> stuff = new List<string>(); //full of stuff
for(int i = stuff.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    //Edited here for more efficiency.
    for (int x = i - 1; x > 0; x--)
    {
        if (stuff[x] == stuff[i])
        {
            stuff.RemoveAt(i);
            break; //or possibly continue;
        }
    }
}
```

This was hand-coded here so it might have a few syntactical errors, feel free to shoot me an edit if you find something's not quite right.

If you're a wizard with LINQ you could also try grouping the objects in the list and then just selecting the first object in each group for your output list..

Comment: Someone probably did not like for/i/x.. people tend to not like imperative way these days

Comment: I'm pretty sure LINQ is (much) slower than a double for. People rely far too much on one liners in c#.

Comment: Is this correct? Once the removeat is done, list size is reduced and you're still looping based on the original index?

Comment: Izzy: Many times the data sets are small and readability is then far more important. With large sets, the speed comes first from reducing the problem set, then from algortihm "shape", and finally from the algorithm's implementation. Yours is very close in the shape to what other's proposed. Scan from head/tail, break early, etc. IMHO, that all makes pessimistic 0.5*n^2. One might optimize for some certain distribution, but no one expects the SpanishInquisition, so pessimistic cases just hit and dissapear. I actually like inoptimized 1-linears because they first force you to review the problem.

Answer (score -2):

you can use the LINQ Except call,

```
List a = new List();
a.Add("a");
a.Add("b");
a.Add("c");
List b = new List();
b.Add("b");
b.Add("c");
b.Add("d");
List c = a.Except(b);
```

list c will contain only item "a";

you can even make it more clever by giving a compare object,

```
List c = a.Except(b, new CompareObject());
```

Comment: I think you need to reread the question more carefully. It's not just about set difference.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl then what is it?

Comment: It's also not _just about_ set difference, because the other set is yet unknown and must be determined. If you want to answer, then explain how to prepare the Comparer so that it performs the required checks. Currently, you've got only 50% of the answer. I do not call for code, just some short explanation.